# Always a TIE! Rock Paper Scissors game

Tags: javascript, html

This is my first game and code for a Rock Paper Scissors game with some tweaks from CodeAcademy. I've been stuck for two hours trying to figure out why it keeps resulting in a tie.

This is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE  html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Rock Paper Scissors</title>
</head>

<body>
<form>
Rock
<input type="checkbox" id="rock">
Paper
<input type="checkbox" id="paper">
Scissors
<input type="checkbox" id="scissors">
<button onclick="startGame()">Start<button>
</form>

<script src="userInt.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Javascript Code:

```
function userChoice(){
var rock = document.getElementById("rock").checked;
var scissors = document.getElementById("scissors").checked;
var paper = document.getElementById("paper").checked;

}
function computerChoice(){
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
computerChoice = "rock";

} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
computerChoice = "paper";

} else {
computerChoice = "scissors";
} 

}
function compare(userChoice, computerChoice){
if (userChoice === computerChoice){
    return "The result is a tie!";

}
if (userChoice ==="rock"){

    if(computerChoice ==="scissors"){
        return "rock wins";
    }else{
        return "paper wins";
    }
}
    if(userChoice ==="paper"){

        if (computerChoice ==="scissors"){
            return "paper wins"
        }else{
            return "scissors wins"
        }
    }

    if(userChoice ==="scissors"){

        if (computerChoice ==="rock"){
            return "rock wins"
        }else{
            return "scissors wins"
        }
    }
}   

function startGame(){
var getUserChoice = userChoice();
var getComputerChoice = computerChoice();
var endGame = compare(getUserChoice, getComputerChoice);
alert(endGame)
}
```

Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 problems in your code:

1. `userChoice` returns nothing(`undefined`)
2. `computerChoice` returns nothing(`undefined`)

---

```
function userChoice() {
    var rock = document.getElementById("rock").checked;
    var scissors = document.getElementById("scissors").checked;
    var paper = document.getElementById("paper").checked;

    if (rock) {
        return 'rock';
    }

    if (scissors) {
        return 'scissors';
    }

    if (paper) {
        return 'paper';
    }

}

function computerChoice() {
    var computerChoice = Math.random();
    if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
        computerChoice = "rock";

    } else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
        computerChoice = "paper";

    } else {
        computerChoice = "scissors";
    }

    return computerChoice;

}

function compare(userChoice, computerChoice) {
    if (userChoice === computerChoice) {
        return "The result is a tie!";

    }
    if (userChoice === "rock") {

        if (computerChoice === "scissors") {
            return "rock wins";
        } else {
            return "paper wins";
        }
    }
    if (userChoice === "paper") {

        if (computerChoice === "scissors") {
            return "paper wins"
        } else {
            return "scissors wins"
        }
    }

    if (userChoice === "scissors") {

        if (computerChoice === "rock") {
            return "rock wins"
        } else {
            return "scissors wins"
        }
    }
}

function startGame() {
    var getUserChoice = userChoice();
    console.log(getUserChoice);
    var getComputerChoice = computerChoice();
    console.log(getComputerChoice);
    var endGame = compare(getUserChoice, getComputerChoice);
    alert(endGame);
}
```

[Working demo on JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ctz03gwm/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Your userChoice() and computerChoice() return nothing.

```
function userChoice() {
    var choice;
    ['rock', 'scissors', 'paper'].some(function (e) {
        if (document.getElementById(e).checked) {
            choice = e;
            return true;
        }
    });
    return choice;
}

function computerChoice() {
    var computerChoice = Math.random();
    if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
        computerChoice = "rock";
    } else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
        computerChoice = "paper";
    } else {
        computerChoice = "scissors";
    }
    return computerChoice;
}
```